# Error calculating dates with Date.getTime()

Tags: javascript

I've got this code:

```
f_sal = new Date( f_sal.getFullYear(), f_sal.getMonth(), f_sal.getDate() ); 
f_reg = new Date( f_reg.getFullYear(), f_reg.getMonth(), f_reg.getDate() ); 

var unDia = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
difDias = Math.round((f_reg.getTime() - f_sal.getTime()) / unDia );
```

If f_sal value is 6/9/2012 and f_reg value is 7/9/2012, difDias value is 1 day (correct). But if f_reg value is 6/10/2012, difDias value is 31 days... The right result would be 30 days.

Where's my fault?

Answer (score 1):

I think it makes more sense to use `Math.floor()` instead of `Math.round()`.
So you should do:

```
difDias = Math.floor((f_reg.getTime() - f_sal.getTime()) / unDia );
```

Comment: Yes, with floor much better, but this is not the right answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the problem was defining the months, because they are zero based, so now I do f_sal.getMonth() - 1, and the problem is solved.